# Draw the poles and zeros in the z plane for a system with poles at 0.45±j1.06 and zeros at 0.58±j2.06 Also plot the magnitude response of the system

Tags: frequency-response, magnitude

Can you guys share 1 resource that solves similar type of this problem. This is not do my homework post. I just want a place which solves this type of problem. If you have pdf in book or sth, do share that.

Comment: Start with your class materials, that should be in there. There are different ways of drawing the magnitude response and most teachers want it the way they teach it in class. Seems also a bit of a trick question: have you covered "stability" yet ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For the first part, considering the poles/zeroes you are given are on the $s$-plane map them on the $z$-plane using the transformation $z = e^{sT}$. Depending on the sample interval $T$ you are given, you may find that the discrete-time system is actually not unstable unlike the continuous one (Real part of the poles is positive).

Comment: Why do you think that the given poles and zeros are in the $s$-plane?

Comment: @MattL. You're right, I have made appropriate edits to my initial reply. However I think drawing four dots on paper without any prior processing would be a way too trivial HW problem for any signals & systems course, let alone a question here.